# Use jQuery to remove tabindex everytime it is added to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqxgrid

I feel dirty even asking this question.  But here it is:

I am using jqxGrid from jqWidgets.  It adds `tabindex="1"` automatically to its grid.  No mater what.

And it puts it back if you so much as mouse over the thing.

Crazy stuff.  I am hoping that there is a way to remove it, but I found a jqWidgets question asked about [this 4 years ago and it got no responses](https://www.jqwidgets.com/community/topic/removing-grids-tabindex/#post-97995).

I know it will probably kill performance (and frankly I will probably not use it).  But my frustration has me asking anyway...

**Is there an event I can catch, so I know when `tabindex` is added to a specific element (and then remove it)?  (or even better block it)**

Comment: Uhh, this *is* dirty. I like it. What sort of browser support do you need?

Comment: Also, let me get ahead of your response and point you straight to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom - tl;dr: `MutationObserver`

Comment: @vzwick - ie 11. But now that the rage is clearing a bit (I am done with work for the day), I am less inclined actually to do something like this. But I am still wanting to know just in case.

Comment: Yeah, the "I want it to be perfect, although no one will ever notice" rabbit hole is all too easy to fall into ...

Comment: So, I was bored (and it seemed a fun problem to work through), it does seem to work on IE 11 (though it - wrongly? - complains about a missing `;`): https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6gbLk313/1/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `MutationObserver` approach mentioned above doesn't work out because of browser constraints (and/or because it is deprecated in Level 3), you can always fall back to the brute-force

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    $('#grid [tabindex]').removeAttr('tabindex');
}, 200);
```